# Proper and fast way to TELNET in PHP. Sockets or cURL

Tags: php, sockets, curl, telnet

Almost all examples of the TELNET implementations in PHP are with sockets (*fsockopen*). This does not work for me, because it takes an unacceptable amount of time (~ 60 seconds).

I have tried *fsockopen* for other purposes and found it slow in contrast to cURL.

**Question #1:** Why are sockets that slow?

**Update:** I found we need to set [stream_set_timeout](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-timeout.php) function, and we can control the socket execution time. I'm curious how to set the proper timeout or how to make it "stop waiting" once the response is received.

---

I can't get the same thing implemented with cURL. Where should I put the commands which I need to send to telnet? Is *CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST* the proper option?  I'm doing something like this:

```
class TELNETcURL{

    public $errno;
    public $errstr;
    private $curl_handle;
    private $curl_options = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "telnet://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:<port>",
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 40,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => FALSE,
        CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS => CURLPROTO_TELNET
    );

    function __construct(){
        $this->curl_handle = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($this->curl_handle, $this->curl_options);
    }

    public function exec_cmd($query) {
        curl_setopt($this->curl_handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $query."\r\n");
        $output = curl_exec($this->curl_handle);
        return $output;
    }

    function __destruct(){
        curl_close($this->curl_handle);
    }

}
```

And then something similar to this:

```
$telnet = new TELNETcURL();
print_r($telnet->exec_cmd("<TELNET commands go here>"));
```

I am getting "Max execution time exceeded 30 seconds" on curl_exec command.

**Question #2:** What is wrong with the cURL implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sockets are not slow. sockets are the base for communication. Curl uses sockets to open a connection to the remote server. Everything works on sockets (i think).
I don't think you can use curl to use a telnet service, well, that's not entirely true, i guess you can connect and send a single command. Curl was designed with http protocol in mind which is stateless (you open a connection, send a request, wait a reply and the close the connection).
Sockets are the only option.

> I am getting "Max execution time exceeded 30 seconds" on curl_exec command.

My guess is that the remote server is the culprit. check to see if it works using a regular terminal client, or increase the max_execution_time in php ini.

**UPDATE**

It seems it is possible to use curl for telnet, check this:
http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/documentation/curl/

But i still think you are better off using sockets.

Comment: Sockets... I noticed sockets are closing the connection only after timeout has been reached. Meaning, if I set 1 sec timeout, socket will execute for 1 sec (not less). I need to use this as soon as the operation completes, because I'm using it in realtime application. If I set small timeout, the operation might not complete (if it's long time taking operation), then I will receive nothing. With cURL it is completing immediately. So I don't know how to do that with sockets. Please advise.

Comment: Yes, cURL supports TELNET, but I don't know how to implement it in PHP. I didn't find working example on the net.

Answer (score 3):

what you need to be doing is using NON-Blocking IO  and then Poll for the response.  what you are doing now is waiting/hanging for a response that never comes -- thus the timeout.

Personally I've written a lot of socket apps in php they work great -- and I detest cURL as buggy, cumbersome, and highly insecure...  just read their bug list you should be appalled.

Go read the Excellent PHP manual complete with many examples for how to do Polled IO they even give you an example telnet server & client.

Comment: also make sure you are not being blocked by a firewall

Answer (score 0):

use [pfsockopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pfsockopen.php)  instead of fopensock ..its much faster and keeps connection alive all the way