# Php+curl: send raw tcp request

Tags: php, curl, tcp

Is it possible to send raw tcp data stream using curl with php?
I know that fsockopen/fputs is better choice for such sending, and surely I use them when its possible. 
But on some servers socket functions are disabled, and curl is enabled. So in such cases it will be very comfortably use curl, of course if its possible at all.
For example I need

```
$fp = fsockopen($my_ip, $my_port);
fwrite($fp, "test string");
```

I cant use fsockopen, as it's disabled by server config. 
Any tips to do it with curl?

Comment: cURL is for transferring data with URL syntax, supporting DICT, FILE, FTP, FTPS, Gopher, HTTP, HTTPS, IMAP, IMAPS, LDAP, LDAPS, POP3, POP3S, RTMP, RTSP, SCP, SFTP, SMTP, SMTPS, Telnet and TFTP. It will not support any communication with non-URL syntax

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Telnet option of curl as is done here: [Proper and fast way to TELNET in PHP. Sockets are damn slow or how to TELNET with PHP cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411182/proper-and-fast-way-to-telnet-in-php-sockets-are-damn-slow-or-how-to-telnet-wit)

So you won't drag along the http or ftp or whatever protocol.

After that you may try for yourself.